# Is there a limit to the scroll length of a web page?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsp, limit, html

I have a client who is building a business application that will be used with IE8 only.

One of the requirements is to display *all* of the data in a single page. I am anticipating this data table to be somewhere between 3K - 10K pixels in length. In the worst case scenarios, more than 25K pixels.

What are the technical considerations when serving a page that long? Is there a limit on page length and IE would display a error?

The application is Java/Struts based.

Comment: ie6 will die with big pages. Newer browsers do better.. 25k pixels is not that big for IE8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this Javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    var i=10000;
    var buff='';
    while(--i){
        buff+='<br />';
    }
    document.body.innerHTML=buff;
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Test results: 25K is good, 100K is okay, 250K works but has a long delay.

Comment: @Christopher: the delay is likely only the script executing. If you have a really long static website, the important delay you will have is the time needed to download the document from the internet.

Answer (score 2):

The theoretical answer: Your machine resources are finite - so yes, there's a limit.

The practical answer: Take a look at other very long pages, e.g. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html

Answer (score 1):

Try it with:

```
<%
for (int i = 0; i < 25000; i ++) {
  %>test<br /><%
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE10 stops at just under 1534000px in my testing.  The limit includes the height of the viewport into the scrollable area so the actual scrollTop is the limit minus the height of the element.

If you set CSS style -ms-scroll-limit-y-max it will clamp at the maximum allowed value, it seems.  But in my case I stumbled on this number by accident.